# Android XML parsing listview

Tags: android, xml, listview

I using this tutorial http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-xml-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/ to reaching XML parsing,if I want to change the url to this one http://gis.taiwan.net.tw/XMLReleaseALL_public/activity_C_f.xml ,how to do that?  Because the xml format are different.If there is a similar question of this please inform me.Thanks.

There is a  tag in each listitem but my url only 'Infos' at begin which includes all tags.

MainActivity.java

```
   package eason.xml;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    static String ID = "Id";
    static String NAME = "Name";
    static String WEBSITE = "Website";
    static String PICTURE1 = "Picture";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadXML().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private void parseRequestResultXML(InputStream stream) {

            arraylist=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

            try {
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
                parser.setInput(stream, null);

                HashMap<String, String> map = null;

                int eventType = parser.getEventType();
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    switch (parser.getEventType()) {

                        case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                            //Log.i("TAG", " Start document " + parser.getName());
                            break;

                        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                            //Log.i("TAG", " Start tag " + parser.getName());
                            String tag=parser.getName();

                            if(tag.equals("Info")){ //read values from Info tag
                                Log.i("TAG","reading info");
                                ID=parser.getAttributeValue(null, "Id");
                                NAME=parser.getAttributeValue(null, "Name");
                                WEBSITE=parser.getAttributeValue(null, "Website");
                                PICTURE1=parser.getAttributeValue(null,"Picture1");
                                //do same for other values

                                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                map.put("Id", ID);
                                map.put("Name", NAME);
                                map.put("Website", WEBSITE);
                                arraylist.add(map);
                            }

                            break;

                        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                            //Log.i("TAG", " End tag " + parser.getName());
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    eventType=parser.next(); //get next event type
                }

                //reading all values from list
                for (Map<String,String> e : arraylist) {
                    Log.d("TAG"," Row ID "+e.get("Id")+" Name "+e.get("Name")+" Website "+e.get("Website")+" Picture1 "+e.get("Picture1"));
                }

            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android XML Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
// Retrieve nodes from the given URL address
            InputStream stream = parser.getInputStreamFromUrl("http://gis.taiwan.net.tw/XMLReleaseALL_public/activity_C_f.xml");
            if (stream != null) {
                try {parseRequestResultXML(stream);
                stream.close();}catch(IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

}}
```

ListViewAdapter

```
package eason.xml;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView NAME;
        TextView START;
        TextView WEBSITE;
        ImageView Picture1;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        NAME = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        START = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
        WEBSITE = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);

        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        Picture1 = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        NAME.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.ID));
        START.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.NAME));
        WEBSITE.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.WEBSITE));
        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.PICTURE1), Picture1);
        // Capture ListView item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                resultp = data.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("Id", resultp.get(MainActivity.ID));
                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("Name", resultp.get(MainActivity.NAME));
                // Pass all data population
                intent.putExtra("Website",
                        resultp.get(MainActivity.WEBSITE));
                // Pass all data flag
                intent.putExtra("Picture1", resultp.get(MainActivity.PICTURE1));
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

XML parser

```
package eason.xml;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

public class XMLParser {

    public XMLParser() {

    }

    // Retrive XML from URL
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return xml;
    }

    // Retrive DOM element
    public Document getDomElement(String xml) {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
    }

    // Retrive Node element
    public final String getElementValue(Node elem) {
        Node child;
        if (elem != null) {
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
                for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child
                        .getNextSibling()) {
                    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    // Retrive Node Value
    public InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            return httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why negative comment?Why don't you leave a comment?

Comment: Change the URL in getXmlFromUrl?

Comment: Don't you notice the tag format is different?

Answer (score 1):

Change the URL in `getXmlFromUrl()` and then change the keys in `parser.getValue(e, **RANK**)`. Whatever your format is, you need to specify the keys to get the data and then save accordingly.

Comment: Not works,the begin tag is <Info different from the tutorial tag <ranking> which include each listitem.

Comment: dude you need to change the keys to get the data. It the new tag is info then you can check it like this if(tag.equals("Info")). Everything is written in your code.

Answer (score 1):

In that tutorial Author is reading values from `TEXT` tag of XML. But in your case you need to get values from there attribute name.

```
private void parseRequestResultXML(InputStream stream) {

        arraylist=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        try {
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(stream, null);

            HashMap<String, String> map = null;

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                switch (parser.getEventType()) {

                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    //Log.i("TAG", " Start document " + parser.getName());
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    //Log.i("TAG", " Start tag " + parser.getName());
                    String tag=parser.getName();

                    if(tag.equals("Info")){ //read values from Info tag
                        Log.i("TAG","reading info");
                        String id=parser.getAttributeValue(null, "Id");
                        String name=parser.getAttributeValue(null, "Name");
                        String website=parser.getAttributeValue(null, "Website");
                        //do same for other values

                        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("id", id);
                        map.put("name", name);
                        map.put("website", website);
                        arraylist.add(map);
                    }   

                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    //Log.i("TAG", " End tag " + parser.getName());
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                eventType=parser.next(); //get next event type
            }

            //reading all values from list
            for (Map<String,String> e : arraylist) {
                Log.d("TAG"," Row ID "+e.get("id")+" Name "+e.get("name")+" Website "+e.get("website"));
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
```

**UPDATED:**
Add this method in `XMLParser.java`

```
public InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            return httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In `doInBackground`

```
arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
// Retrieve nodes from the given URL address
InputStream stream = parser.getInputStreamFromUrl("http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/xmlparseimgtxt.xml");
if (stream != null){
    parseRequestResultXML(stream);
    stream.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.But I do not know which line should be replace from your code.

Comment: just call method with inputstream as parameter.

Comment: stream.close();  says on handle exception

Comment: Where should I put   private void parseRequestResultXML?

Comment: inside DownloadXML... about stream.close() catch the exception. ie put it in try block.

Comment: Can you please check my Listviewadapter and Mainactivity again?Because your answer only include part of code and there still mistake in it,I need to edit other part myself.But I not so sure is it right or not.

Comment: 1.Should I delete getXmlFromUrl and getDomElement method in XMLparser class? 2.the String xml in inputstream says never used.

Comment: delete things which you don't need and not using. About Adapter nothing to do, your adapter is just fine.

Comment: Can you also check XML parser class ,which one should be remain?

Comment: as I told remove method and variable which u r not using. like `getXmlFromUrl`  and `getDomElement` etc. Is above code wokring or not.

Comment: not working.The screen is empty. 304-361/system_process W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger﹕ setKernelCountSet(10021, 0) failed with errno -1

Comment: Should I upload my project to github then you can edit it directly.